# Convert ASCII String to 7-bit GSM coding scheme

Tags: c, encoding, ascii, gsm, pdu

A simple routine i wrote for converting `ASCII` string to corresponding `7-bit GSM` coding scheme:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/* convert ascii input string to 7-bit GSM alphabet */
bool ascii_to_gsm(const char* in, uint8_t len, uint8_t* out, uint8_t start_indx) {
    if (in == NULL || out == NULL || len == 0)
        return false;

    uint8_t nshift = 7;
    memcpy(out + start_indx, in, len);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        nshift = (nshift == 255) ? 7 : nshift;
        uint16_t l = out[start_indx + i];
        uint16_t h = out[start_indx + i + 1];
        h = (h << nshift--) | l;
        out[start_indx + i] = h;
        out[start_indx + i + 1] = h >> 8;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    char data[] = "ASCIIASCII";
    uint8_t buff[sizeof(data) - 1];
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    ascii_to_gsm(data, sizeof(buff), buff, 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); i++) {
        printf("\n buff[%d]=%02x", i, buff[i]);
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

For strings like `ASCII` or `TEST` it's working fine and output is `C1E9309904` and `D4E2940A`respectively.

But for string `ASCIIASCII` some output byte is wrong:
`C1E930990C4E87498024`

The result should be: `C1E930990C4E87C924`

Don't know what part, i'm wrong.

Concepts about GSM coding can be found [here](https://github.com/vilts/PDU/blob/master/docs/sms_construction.pdf).

I use [this](http://www.twit88.com/home/utility/sms-pdu-encode-decode) online encoder to compare results

Comment: *Why isn't this code working* is offtopic for SO.

Comment: Hmmm, the "byte" length of output differs between `C1E930990C4E87498024` and `C1E930990C4E87C924`.

Comment: It looks like your code generates one byte of output for every one byte of input. (Actually it seems to generate *two* bytes of output for each one byte of input, but it seems to overwrite half of them, which you might want to look into.)  But if GSM is a 7-bit encoding, I'm guessing you want to generate, on average, 7/8 of a byte for each byte of input, or 7 bytes of output for each 8 bytes of input.  "ASCIIASCII" is 10 bytes long, you generate 10 bytes of output, the correct answer is 9 bytes of output.

Comment: @SteveSummit. Yes that's pretty correct, an `SMS` of max 140 byte in `GSM` coding could be 160 chars length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But for string ASCIIASCII some output byte is wrong:
>   C1E930990C4E87498024
>   The result should be:
>   C1E930990C4E87C924

OP's code does not take into account the output may have a shorter length than the input.

If the input is 10 ASCII characters, that is 70 bits.  The output needs to be ceiling(70/8) or 9 bytes.  Also see [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944276/convert-ascii-string-to-7-bit-gsm-coding-scheme/49945287#comment86905717_49944276).

---

A simplified code for reference that lacks a `start_indx`.  Since input is a *string*  ("converting ASCII string"), the input length is not needed.

```
bool ascii_to_gsmA(const char* in, uint8_t* out) {
  unsigned bit_count = 0;
  unsigned bit_queue = 0;
  while (*in) {
    bit_queue |= (*in & 0x7Fu) << bit_count;
    bit_count += 7;
    if (bit_count >= 8) {
      *out++ = (uint8_t) bit_queue;
      bit_count -= 8;
      bit_queue >>= 8;
    }
    in++;
  }
  if (bit_count > 0) {
    *out++ = (uint8_t) bit_queue;
    }
  return true;
}
```